# Including an HTML file with a user control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

edit: While it's not a legitimate answer to my question, I realized I messed up the formatting when I tried to just make the html a string in the user control code. Added a verbatim string literal and double quotes and it works. Still would like to see if there's a way to do what I asked, though.

---

So, I'm building a user control in winforms. It's based off the webbrowser control, and uses an html file to construct a markdown editor.

I feel like I totally missed the boat or something on how to include files as resources (as in the resx file), is that possible for a user control? There doesn't seem to be any folder structure I can use to store the html file as part of the user control 'project'.

I'm planning on eventually packaging the user control into a dll file to use with a bunch of projects.

Is there a way to package an external file with a user control? I'm in visual studio 2013.

Comment: In visual studio, you add it to the solution (where ever you want it) and then click it and click Copy to output

Comment: Problem is, user controls don't have a solution. Trying to find a way to stick the html file with the user control somehow, so when I make a dll of it, I don't also have to place the html file somewhere in the file structure of whatever project uses the user control.

Comment: Hmmm I dont think that is possible, unless you stored the html in a resx file then included that in the solution, but that would be auto picked up when you build the dll

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you nut construct the html via code then use streamwriter to create it and then load it into the browser control

Comment: That's possible. I tried that the first time and it didn't work, but I could've messed the syntax up.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of your original and I will see if I can help
Update your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I'm just stupid and you totally can add resource files to a user control. I didn't realize I had visual studio on 'class view' instead of 'solution view'.